# Regular expression in note pad++

Tags: regex-lookarounds

I have this kind of text 
ACORN HOME AND GARDEN   3870 Due West Road NW Marietta Georgia 30064
i want the text to be like something below

ACORN HOME AND GARDEN
3870 Due West Road NW Marietta Georgia 30064

I tried writing a regular expression

```
^([A-Z]$)*
```

But this doesnot give me the result which i want.

Could anyone help me in finding the exact regular expression

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
^([A-Za-z\s]*)(\d{4}[A-Za-z0-9\s\d]*)$
```

This contains two capturing groups:

1. `([A-Za-z\s]*)`
2. `(\d{4}[A-Za-z0-9\s\d]*)`

This will split the data into:

1. `ACORN HOME AND GARDEN`
2. `3870 Due West Road NW Marietta Georgia 30064`

Be aware that this will unlikely work for different address formats as this splits into two groups when it hits the first series of decimal digits AND the first set of decimal digits in this case MUST be 4 digits long in order for the split to occur.

It's going to be hard to split this type of information as it's quite irregular. Regex works best with well formatted data.

Here are some tools that might help:

http://www.regexper.com/

http://www.regexpal.com/

Here is a jsFiddle example:

**HTML**

```
<span id="out"></span>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var addr = "ACORN HOME AND GARDEN 3870 Due West Road NW Marietta Georgia 30064";
    var regex = /^([A-Za-z\s]*)(\d{4}[A-Za-z0-9\s\d]*)$/;
    // Try changing the index [0] to [1] or [2] to see a different result.
    $("#out").text(regex.exec(addr)[0]);
});
```

Try here: http://jsfiddle.net/sNEZV/